# Merging Csv files based on ID

Tags: c#

I am trying to merge multiple files into one file based on ID value.
so far i tried this

```
List<FileDTO> firstFile = GetData<FileDTO>("1.csv");
List <FileDTO> secondFile = GetData<FileDTO>("2.csv");
var result = from f in firstFile
             join s in secondFile on f.ID equals s.ID into g
             select new FileDTO
             {
                 ID = f.ID,
                 Name = f.name,
                 Sports = g.First().sports,
                 Country = g.First().country
             };

SaveToCsv(result, "combined.csv"); // this function saves the combined CSV
```

I am able to merge 2 files based on ID next i need to merge n number of files from an intranet folder,  but i am stuck in Linq query how to join n numbers of file List data based on ID. Any suggestion or help into right direction. Thanks

Comment: well.. It seems like you're asking for `GroupBy` expression; However, it's unclear.  Are you asking how to loop through a collection of List<FileDTO> and join?

Comment: Yes loop through a collection of List<FileDTO> and join,  with 2 files like firstFile and secondFile i can successfully merge the 2 files Data into one based on Id. I just need to do that for 100 of files.

Comment: Define "merge". What does it mean to you? Concatenate? Append and sort? Full join? Dedupe?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn just combining the data of n number of files.

Comment: That's still pretty vague. Computers are the ultimate pedantic machines, which means as programmers we often need to be the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel the proper implementation of this will account for System.IO and memory considerations; So, Beyond handling this ***n*** `List<FileDTO>` issue, you may end up resorting to refactoring your implementation to use Async-Await Tasks and using Concurrent namespace collection types.

The answer\implementation I'll scope to, and provide here, will reflect on loaded\serialized structures as `List<IEnumerable<FileDTO>>` instance. I won't use Lambda expressions for this example or explaination.

---

As an alternative to iterating through a collection of `IEnumerable<FileDTO>` and performing joins, you could handle ***n*** `List<FileDTO>` by using Linq's `Enumerable<T>.Aggregate` and a `Enumerable<T>.GroupBy` methods.

You will initialize and pass a new `List<FileDTO>` instance as the first parameter of the `Aggregate` method. The next parameter is a delegate, which is a reducer function.  In this delegate, you would do an `AddRange` of the second argument (`next`) on the first argument (`last`) of the reducer function, `last` is the instance of `List<FileDTO>` that was initially passed as an empty `List<FileDTO>`, and will be the return of each call\iteration using the reducer function delegate).

Finally, you would do a `GroupBy` on the result then project with `.Select`, and handled `Sports`, `Country` or any other type of collection property appropriately (with `FirstOrDefault?.<property> ?? default` or `SelectMany` to flatten - and perhaps `Distinct`, if need be);

```
var result GenerateFileDTOSampleData().Aggregate(new List<FileDTO>(), ReduceFileDTOs, GroupFileDTOByIdName);

SaveToCsv(result, "combined.csv"); // this function saves the combined CSV

List<FileDTO> ReduceFileDTOs(List<FileDTO> last, IEnumerable<FileDTO> next)
{
    last.AddRange(next.ToArray());
    return last;
}

IEnumerable<FileDTO> GroupFileDTOByIdName(IEnumerable<FileDTO> fileDTOs) => fileDTOs.GroupBy(item => (item.ID, item.Name))
    .Select(groupedItems => new FileDTO()
    {
        ID = groupedItems.Key.ID,
        Name = groupedItems.FirstOrDefault(HasName)?.Name,
        Sports = groupedItems.FirstOrDefault(HasSports)?.Sports ?? default,
        Country = groupedItems.FirstOrDefault(HasCountry)?.Country ?? default
    });

bool HasName(FileDTO fileDto) => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileDto.Name);
bool HasSports(FileDTO fileDto) => fileDto.Sports.Any();
bool HasCountry(FileDTO fileDto) => fileDto.Country.Any();
```

The above uses the following method to generated the sample data, but you should utilize your file reads.

```
IEnumerable<List<FileDTO>> GenerateFileDTOSampleData() => new[] { 
    new List<FileDTO>
    {
        new FileDTO {ID = 1, Name = "1", Sports = new [] {"Football", "Basketball"}, Country = new [] {"usa" } },
        new FileDTO {ID = 2, Name = "2", Sports = new [] {"Football", "Basketball"}, Country = new [] {"usa" } },
        new FileDTO {ID = 3, Name = "3", Sports = new [] {"Football", "Basketball"}, Country = new [] {"usa" } }
    }, 
    new List<FileDTO>
    {
        new FileDTO {ID = 2, Name = "2", Sports = new [] {"Football", "Basketball"}, Country = new [] {"usa" } }
    }, 
    new List<FileDTO>
    {
        new FileDTO {ID = 4, Name = "4", Sports = new [] {"Football", "Basketball"}, Country = new [] {"usa" } }
    }
};
```

#### UPDATE: Sample of `Join` in `Aggregate` (with `Skip` and `FirstOrDefault`)

Be aware that `Join`, or `GroupJoin`, are equivalent to a `LEFT OUTTER JOIN`, in that the first\outter recordset\collection does not alter in size based on whether or not an inner record exists or can join.

```
var data = GenerateFileDTOSampleData().ToList();

var r = data.Skip(1).Aggregate(data.FirstOrDefault(), ReduceGroupJoinedFileDTOs);

List<FileDTO> ReduceGroupJoinedFileDTOs(List<FileDTO> last, IEnumerable<FileDTO> next)
{
  return last.GroupJoin(next,
    (outter) => outter.ID,
    (inner) => inner.ID,
    (outter, joined) => new FileDTO
    {
      ID = outter.ID,
      Name = joined.FirstOrDefault(HasName)?.Name,
      Sports = joined.FirstOrDefault(HasSports)?.Sports ?? default,
      Country = joined.FirstOrDefault(HasCountry)?.Country ?? default
    }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I want emphasize - given there is an estimate of 100 files to be stream read and cvs serialized, Task and Worker Thread congestion could pose an issue to your work.  So, I do recommend Concurrent namespace and handling be a consideration to your implementation @MMK .

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation Brett.  do you suggest shall i go down the root of using StreamReader and StreamWriter?

Comment: Can we do join based on ID?  @Brett Caswell

Comment: you can @MMK, in the reducer delegate part.  I'll provide update this answer to provide that solution

Comment: OK Brett Thank you

Comment: no @MMK, I'm not going to do that.  my answer demonstrates how to handle iterating a collection of `List<List<T>>` using `Aggregate` with Linq.  I'm address the issue you raised and were having in how to handle that - I am not doing your work problem.  note: `Join` doesn't work that way in the first place, it is equivalent to an `Left Inner Join`.  so you aren't going to get `15,,,USA` as a result in your current 2 item snippet..

Comment: I got that Brett